# bootstrap popover misplacement when adding content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to write function that when you click on a button, textarea is adding in the bottom of my popover content.
the problem is that when the textarea is shown the popover extend down and hides the text.
i want the popover extend only up (save the bottom placement and the original width)
help?

here is my code:

html:

```
<div class="popover-markup">
  <a href="#" class="trigger">
    This link triggers the popover.
  </a>
  <span class="content hide">
    <p>This is the popover content.
    </p>
      <button id="clickme" onclick="showText()">click me</button>
      <textarea class="textarea"></textarea>
  </span>
</div>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.popover-markup > .trigger').popover({
        html: true,
        title: function () {
            return $(this).parent().find('.head').html();
        },
        content: function () {
            return $(this).parent().find('.content').html();
        },
        container: 'body',
        placement: 'top',
        html: true
    });

    $('.textarea').hide();


});
function showText() {
    $('.textarea').show();
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a nasty hack where the content is replaced just in time for the popover to calculate a new correct position when invoked again.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        .container {
            margin-top: 200px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <button id="my-show-popover" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container=".container" data-toggle="popover"
                data-placement="top" data-html="true" data-trigger="manual">
            Popover on top
        </button>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var popoverNoTextAreaContent = "Nasty hobbitses. <button type='button' id='my-show-text-area-button' class='btn btn-default'>Click</button>",
                popoverWithTextAreaContent = popoverNoTextAreaContent + "<textarea></textarea>";
            $('#my-show-popover').click(function () {
                $(this).attr('data-content', popoverNoTextAreaContent).popover('show');
            });
            $(document).on('click', '#my-show-text-area-button', function () {
                $('#my-show-popover').attr('data-content', popoverWithTextAreaContent).popover('show');
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```